# Refresh Div From EJS Template Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, ejs

I've got a basic user-to-user messaging service on an Express app, and when a user submits a new message, AJAX sends a POST request to the server to update the conversation in the database.

When the AJAX POST has completed, I'd like to refresh the div containing the thread to show the message which has just been submitted.

I've tried:

```
$("#mymsgs").load("message_view.ejs #mymsgs > *", "");
```

as I found from other questions / Google, but the div doesn't refresh, and I don't get any error messages. I've noticed that if the path to the EJS file is `"/message_view.ejs"` then I get a 404, *but* without the "/", but *with* a spelling mistake in the file name, I don't get any errors, which seems very odd to me.

Is this this right way to go about refreshing a message thread without reloading the entire page, or is there some other way I don't know about?

Thanks a lot!! :D

Comment: After saving the message to your db, fetch the updated data and send the data as a response back `res.send("youtdata")` . In your client side AJAX code save the response content to a variable. Then fill the DOM with it. Simple regular AJAX.

Comment: Also i think web sockets are more appropriate for this kind of app. Check socket.io.

Comment: Thanks Ali! I'll try your first idea tomorrow and look into web sockets later if I need to.